# Python simple counting script

Tags: python, sendkeys

Im trying to make a script that automatically counts and uses `SendKeys` to print out a range of numbers ,say 1 - 100. I can make the list but I dont know how to convert the numbers so `SendKeys` can type them out because so far I can only make it type keys.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
keyboard = Controller()

count = 0

for i in range (1, 100) :
count = count + 1

time.sleep(5)
keyboard.press(i)
keyboard.release(i)
```

Comment: What have you tried? This just sounds like you can’t make the program do what it’s supposed to do, which is quite a broad issue.

Comment: Ive tried converting the list that the for loop makes into a list of integers and to have sendkeys type them out

Comment: *Post* your attempt; don't simply describe its purpose.  See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  "I don't know how to do this" is not a Stack Overflow issue -- at least, not for things that you can find on line.  "My attempt [see code below] gets the shown error" is what we expect.

Comment: @Cri That’s exactly what you said in your post. You have to **narrow down** the problem.

Comment: Be specific about the problem you have Crl. Like what is the error you got if so, which part don't you understand and etc.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. The code you posted won't even run due to incorrect indenting.

Comment: Are you looking for [`pynput.keyboard.Controller.type`](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#pynput.keyboard.Controller.type)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're basically there. You don't need `count`, and you need to send the string of the key you want to press, and presumably a new line. As a shortcut you could use the `Controller.type` method.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Key
import time

keyboard = Controller()

def send_range(start, end, wait_time):
    for i in range(start, end+1):
        keyboard.type(str(i))
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        time.sleep(wait_time)

send_range(1, 100, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
keyboard = Controller()

for i in range(0,101):
    keyboard.type(str(i)+'\n')
    time.sleep(5)
```

Remove **'\n'** if u want to print in same line

Answer (score 0):

If you want the easiest solution, you can use `keyboard.type()` to send the characters in the integer one after another.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Key
import time

keyboard = Controller()

for i in range(1,100):
    time.sleep(5)
    keyboard.type(i)
```

If you still want to use `keyboard.press()` and `keyboard.release()`, for example if you want to sleep between each key press rather than between each integer in the list, then you can convert your integer into a string and then iterate through the string, like so

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Key
import time

keyboard = Controller()

for i in range(1,100):
    time.sleep(5)
    for j in str(i):
        keyboard.press(j)
        keyboard.release(j)
```